# How to upload multiple files at once using MultipartConfigElement in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jquery-file-upload

I am using Spring Boot 1.1.3 with the `CommonsMultipartResolver` to allow uploading of multiple files at once.

I get this stacktrace when I try to upload a file bigger than 1 MB:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: 
The field files[] exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileUploadBase.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
```

I tried setting the max upload size like this:

```
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize( 100 * MEGABYTE_IN_BYTES );
    return resolver;
}
```

However, this does not work. I have found this [Spring guide on upoading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) and there they use `MultipartConfigFactory` instead. However, I now need to use the `MultipartFile` class instead of `MultipartHttpServletRequest` in my controller.

With the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` I could do `getFileMap()` to get all the files, but there is no such method on `MultipartFile`.

Any ideas on how to work with `MultipartConfigFactory` and multiple files? I am using jquery-file-upload on the client if that would matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no need to use the `MultipartFile` in the Controller, you can also use the `MultipartHttpServletRequest`. This is the signature of my `@RestController` annotated class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{datasheetId}/addDoc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Secured(ROLE_USER)
public ResponseEntity<?> addDocumentToDatasheet( Principal principal,
                                                 @PathVariable("datasheetId") long datasheetId,
                                                 MultipartHttpServletRequest request ) throws IOException
{
     Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = request.getFileMap();
     // handle fileMap further...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The right way to increase upload limit is to set property
`multipart.maxFileSize=10Mb`
In your `application.properties` file. You can read more on this topic here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062232/668417
and here
[MultipartProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java)

Answer (score 4):

The question was asked with regard to Spring Boot 1.1.3. As time marches forward the accepted solutions no longer work with newer versions of Spring Boot. However the problem of increasing the maximum allowable upload size persists.

I am writing this as of Spring Boot 1.4.2, so this solution may not be correct in perpetuity.

From the spring guide to [uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) the new properties are thus:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10Mb
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

Answer (score 1):

for the size problem in a my project I use this properties in application.properties:

```
multipart.max-file-size=100Mb
multipart.max-request-size=100Mb
```

for the case of have multiple file I suggest of use a bean like this

```
@Data
class MultipartDTO{

    private MultipartFile file1; 
    private MultipartFile file2;
    .....
    private MultipartFile filen; 

    //eventually other proerties
}
```

then of course in your controller you colud have a thing like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/multipartUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity multipartCall(MultipartDTO multipartDTO){
    ....
}
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: I use an approach like this in a my open source project: https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary/blob/master/book-repository-service/src/main/java/it/valeriovaudi/documentlibrary/endpoint/BookServiceEndPoint.java