# Spring Boot: ClassNotFoundException when configuring maxUploadSize of CommonMultipartResolver

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, file-upload, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot for my web application and I'm trying to configure the maxUploadSize of Spring's CommonMultipartResolver. Currently, it seems to be limited by a Spring (?) default size of 1 MB. The upload is done through a REST interface, and the method signature looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Everytime I try to upload a bigger file, a FileSizeLimitExceededException is thrown:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileUploadBase.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:296)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2737)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3096)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1145)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:382)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

### Things I have tried, but did not work:

#### Setting Tomcat properties

Since my web app is running on Tomcat (not the embedded one, but a separate external one), I tried configuring the size by changing the Tomcat configuration as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat). Unfortunately, this has no effect, as the max upload size still remains at 1 MB.

#### Configuring Spring's CommonMultipartResolver by annotation

Since the value of 1MB seems to come from the CommonMultipartResolver (I can see that the value of 1MB is set when debugging), I tried configuring Spring via annotation like this:

```
@Configuration 
public class CoreConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50 * 1024 * 1024);
    return multipartResolver;
    }

}
```

But when I start up Tomcat, the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    at myapp.server.CoreConfig.commonsMulipartResolver(CoreConfig.java:40)
    at myapp.server.CoreConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b64a88.CGLIB$commonsMulipartResolver$3(<generated>)
    at myapp.server.CoreConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b64a88$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac8c6ee5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at myapp.server.CoreConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b64a88.commonsMulipartResolver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
```

#### Configuration via XML

Instead of an annotation-driven configuration, I tried a configuration via XML similar to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception), but I'm getting the same ClassNotFoundException as above.

### Additional Info

Spring Boot Starter 1.1.9

Tomcat 7.0.54

Pom.xml of the server

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp.server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>myapp.server.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: And have you tried setting the `multipart.maxFileSize ` property inside an `application.properties` file? As stated by the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) in the file upload section? No need to define your own.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You are making it way to complex.

Just add `spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize` to your `application.properties` file and well that is it. No need to use xml or explicitly define a `MultipartResolver`.

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=10MB
```

This is explained in the section about file uploads in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration).

For all properties check the [`MultipartProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.java) class. The other properties supported are `spring.http.multipart.location`, `spring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize` and `spring.http.multipart.fileSizeThreshold`.

The `ClassNotFoundException` is due to the fact that Spring Boot uses the default Servlet 3.0 support for file uploads NOT commons-fileupload. So if you want to use that, you would have to explicitly add the dependency for it. And ofcourse the `spring.http.multipart.*` properties don't work anymore in that case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the respective docs, I somehow must have missed it :( Since I already have a config class with annotations and I prefer to have all config in one place, I now configure the file size [like this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.java) and setting the file size on `MultipartProperties`.

Comment: For some reason "Mb" throws an exception but "MB" works~

Comment: `500Mb` works fine for me on latest Spring Boot (1.2.7). (Would still be nice if the reference guide had some example values.)

Comment: savior in 2016 :)  nice and clean answer.

Comment: Answer is correct but maybe it should be updated because as of **Spring Boot 1.4 M3** the property has changed to `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size`

Comment: I can confirm `Mb` causes an exception and `MB` works as intended.

Comment: The `Mb` vs `MB` thing in Spring Boot's `multipart.*` config is a pet peeve of mine -- why they decided to confuse people with the `Mb` label is beyond me (*e.g.* in the documentation etc). After all, we're talking about *megabytes* (`MB`) not *megabits* (`Mb`).

Answer (score 3):

```
@Bean
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("5120MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("5120MB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Try adding this in the class where you are defining beans.

Comment: Adding all possible variants of yml based config did not work for me. This Did. Thanks Guys.

Comment: pleased to know that.

Answer (score 1):

With spring-boot 1.5.3 you should use the following code in application.yml

```
spring:
 http:
  multipart:
   max-file-size: 10MB
   max-request-size: 10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

for Spring Boot 2.0+ use spring.servlet instead of spring.http

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=30MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```