# How to increase upload file size in JMeter

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, jmeter

I have a script that is uploading file through API rest POST request. I can upload only file with size less than 1048576

An error is

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field filestream exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
```

Maybe someone knows how to increase that size?

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the set up , I think this is on the web side, not the JMeter side.  Usually web applications have a configurable limit on file uploads.  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/MultipartConfigElement.html

Comment: uploading file *thought API  = through

Comment: Alzoid, for that application I can upload big files through UI with the same API.

Comment: @Thanatoz Can you any exception at JMeter end? Also increase the heap size for JMeter and try to upload. Not sure if it will help but you can give it a try.

Comment: "I can upload only file with size less than 1048576" - how did you come up with this number?

Comment: @Thanatoz - that's strange - you need to investigate further - the error you are showing us is from the server.  The max upload size is configurable in the servlet container (tomcat in this case).

Answer (score 2):

No limit on Jmeter side.
From the response you show, it's a server limitation, error is triggered by Tomcat , see:

- The field filestream exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.

See:

- [How to set the max size of upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540028/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file/37551408)
- [Spring Boot: ClassNotFoundException when configuring maxUploadSize of CommonMultipartResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061209/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-when-configuring-maxuploadsize-of-commonmult)